# System.FormatException with knockout brackets {}

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, knockout.js

I'm getting a wierd error with my razor views. When I use {} in my knockout bindings, for example
    `<th data-bind="css:{ active: sortType() =='Date' }">`
I get a exception:

```
System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendFormat(IFormatProvider provider, String format, Object[] args)
   at System.String.Format(IFormatProvider provider, String format, Object[] args)
   at System.String.Format(String format, Object arg0)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime.MappingData.MappingDataUtilities.GenerateSelectorsForElementsWithTagName(List`1 elements, RenderedElement referenceElement, SelectorReferenceType referenceType, String selectorFormatString, SelectorGroupFunction[] groupMethods, Int32 startIndex)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime.MappingData.MappingDataUtilities.GenerateSelectorsWorker(IEnumerable`1 elements, RenderedElement referenceElement, SelectorReferenceType referenceType, String selectorFormatString, SelectorGroupFunction[] groupMethods)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime.MappingData.MappingDataUtilities.GenerateGlobalScopeSelectors(IEnumerable`1 elements)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime.MappingData.MappingDataUtilities.GenerateSelectors(IEnumerable`1 elements)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime.MappingData.MappingDataUtilities.ProcessDataIntoJsonObjects(IEnumerable`1 renderedOutputList, Boolean legacyJsonObjects)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime.Tracing.RequestDataHttpHandler.System.Web.IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
       at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
       at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

This exception does not show on the page, it just gets reported to my via Elmah.

If I replace the {} with thier HTML codes (`&#123;` and `&#125;`) then I don't get the error.

Does anyone know what is causing this?

Thanks,
Phillip

Comment: This is a bug in BrowserLink.

Comment: I have the same problem , it's a bug reported to microsoft and wasn't fixed.
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/870217/browserlink-throws-a-formatexception-on-pages-using-angularjs-ngclass

Answer (score 1):

You can check this link: https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials2013/issues/851

It may be fixed in Visual Studio 2013 Update 4.

Comment: I can confirm it's fixed after installing the update.